# Bounding real valued integral with complex variable

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

This is an exercise from Gamelin's *Complex Analysis*, IV.3.3.

Let $f(z)=\sum_{k=0}^n c_k z^k$ be a polynomial.

My question is in part (b). Before getting into the details, (a) states that

If the $c_k$'s are real, then

$$
\int_{-1}^1 f(x)^2 dx \leq\pi\int_0^{2\pi}|f(e^{i\theta})|^2\frac{d\theta}{2\pi}.
$$

(b) If the $c_k$'s are complex, show that

$$
\int_{-1}^1 |f(x)|^2 dx \leq\pi\int_0^{2\pi}|f(e^{i\theta})|^2\frac{d\theta}{2\pi}.
$$

To solve it, we write $c_k=a_k+ib_k$ ($a_k$ and $b_k$ real).

$$
|\sum_kc_kx^k|^2 = |\sum_ka_kx^k + i\sum_kb_kx^k|^2 = (\sum_ka_kx^k)^2 + (\sum_kb_kx^k)^2,
$$

then

$$
\int_{-1}^1 |f(x)|^2dx = \int_{-1}^1dx((\sum_ka_kx^k)^2 + (\sum_kb_kx^k)^2)\leq \frac{\pi}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta(|\sum_ka_ke^{i\theta k}|^2 + |\sum_kb_ke^{i\theta k}|^2),
$$

where I have used twice part (a). Here is where I am stuck, I cannot find a valid relation between $|\sum_ka_ke^{i\theta k}|^2 + |\sum_kb_ke^{i\theta k}|^2$, and $|f(e^{i\theta})|^2$.